# SlindingMenu slowing toggle

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I want to display for few seconds part of the sliding menu, Here is how I'm doin it:

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showMenu();
        }
    }, 500);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showContent();
        }
    }, 600);
}
```

However, the menu is displaying and disapeared quickly, is there a way to slow down the toggle so that the user can see part of the menu while it's appearing and disapearing slowly?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to slow down the toggle so that the user can see part of the menu while it's > appearing and disapearing slowly?

You would have to change the animation-changing-rate of the `Interpolator` of the `Scroller` [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/CustomViewAbove.java#L44-L49), if you want it to scroll slower. Maybe create a setter for the `Interpolator`, if you want it to scroll slow only temporary (I assume you only want to show to the user, that there is a `SlidingMenu` inside your app, right?), after that you could reset the rate of the `Interpolator` to the default.

Comment: Yep, I want to show the user that there is a SlidingMenu. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I made `mViewAbove` public in **SlidingMenu.java**, then used `scrollBy(int, int)`:

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final View viewAbove = getSlidingMenu().mViewAbove;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewAbove.scrollBy(-60, 0);
        }
    }, 500);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewAbove.scrollBy(60, 0);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on `getSlidingMenu().mViewAbove` ? Thanks!

Comment: `mViewAbove` is a private [attribute](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java#L67) of **SlidingMenu.java** it represents the view rendered on top.